# Converting str to byte from an array and save it to CSV (in Python)

Tags: python, arrays, binary

I would like to save a CSV from an array as binary, but it is not working.

I got this code:

```
    for item in directory:
        originalImage = cv2.imread(input_dir + item)
        grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(originalImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        thresh = 128
        img_binary = cv2.threshold(grayImage, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
        img_not = cv2.bitwise_not(img_binary)
        cv2.imwrite(output_dir + item[:-4] +'.png',img_not)

        if check_var1.get():
            with open(output_dir + "output.csv", "wb") as f:
                np.savetxt(f, img_binary,  fmt="%d", delimiter=",")
                f.write("\n")
```

and I get this Error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

The code only runs when I am using `with open(output_dir + "output.csv", "a") as f:` instead.
How can I convert the array to bytes-like objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly write strings no need to convert it to bytes.
try

```
with open(output_dir + "output.csv", "w") as f:
```

File Modes:

```
wb: write byte
rb: read byte
w: write
r: read
a: append
```

Comment: that is working fine, but what I would like to have at the end is a binary CSV

Comment: If you want to write byte then you will have to use `encode`, but it won't work with `np.savetext`. and whydo you want to write in byte? You can always read byte while reading

Comment: What in your own words is "a binary CSV"?